# Compiling a C extension for Python

Tags: python, c

I've written a C extension for Python (bascially the first thing I've ever coded in C). I've stumbled upon a few compiler errors in header file where I declare the function. Declaration looks like following:

```
void gradient(float* inputs, float* kernels, float* grads, npy_intp* input_dims, npy_intp* kernels_dims, npy_intp* output_dims,  float* g_inputs, float* g_kernels);
```

Compiler throws the following errors

```
gradient.h(1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ')' before '*'
gradient.h(1): error C2081: 'npy_intp': name in formal parameter list illegal
gradient.h(1): error C2143: syntax error: missing '{' before '*'
gradient.h(1): error C2143: syntax error: missing ';' before '*'
gradient.h(1): error C2059: syntax error: 'type'
gradient.h(1): error C2059: syntax error: ')'
```

The error with 'npy_inpt' I think I understand, I should convert that npy_intp array to C ints before passing it to function, is that correct? But what about the first one with pointer ('*')?

Comment: Been a while since I've done any C, but here's my best guess: If the `void gradient ...` line is the first thing in your header file then `npy_intp*` is the problem, since your header doesn't itself `include` the numpy headers that define `npy_intp` as a type.

Comment: But the file that includes "gradient.h" includes the numpy headers, isn't that enough?

Comment: The error you're seeing suggests it is not... but like I say, I'm rusty. It's probably worth trying to add the relevant numpy header[s] to gradient.h and see what happens... and then give me a grovelling apology if it works ;-)

Comment: No it is not. The file "gradient.h" will be compiled with only the headers specified *in it* included. On the other hand, there exist many very fine tools to optimize numerical operations in Python: [Cython](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/) is easy to install, for instance, but there are many more.